# Can't open phonegap wp8 project created by phonegap CLI with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Recently i have developed a phonegap app, now i am going to test it on windows phone.

I have used the phonegap CLI command **phonegap platform add wp8** to add windows phone support to my app. the command downloaded the template and created the project structure in my platforms folder.

AND THE PROBLEM :> when i want to open the ***.sln** file, the visual studio show the following message:
[image]

Comment: phonegap -version :> 4.2.0-0.23.0

Comment: If you go to uninstall program and modify the VS2013 install, you can select the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK to install. To create WP8.1 cordova apps you `phonegap platform add windows` and that will generate both WP8.1 and Windows 8.1 apps, you just to need to have at least VS2013 Update 2 installed, and "Tools for Maintaining Store Apps for Win8" by modifying VS2013 install again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3... it's an add-on to VS2013 update 4 that enables Cordova development inside of the VS IDE. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675

There is a bit of a learning curve, but it effectively replaces the Cordova CLI--in other words, when you build your app with Tools for Apache Cordova you don't use the Cordova command line anymore. And then you no longer care that the .sln file generated by the CLI doesn't work!

Comment: actually i have a problem with font-awesome in wp8, and i need to open the project and change the fonts setting to content to be sure that the fonts are included in the project so the text show properly.
but now i can't open the *.sln file with visual studio to do so.